# TYPO3 6.2 suddenly extreme slow (only frontend!)

Tags: php, mysql, performance, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

We run several TYPO3 websites on Apache (Linux 3.16, mysql 5.6, PHP 5.6). One of our websites (TYPO3 6.2.19) is suddenly extremely slowly but only the frontend. Loading time is always more than 60s but maximum 1.8 min. Site did always run smooth and fast. No changes in server settings were made since the past days.

I already tried to restart apache and sql server, cleared all TYPO3 caches... no changes in frontend.

Any ideas what could cause this error?

Comment: HTTP Status returns **301 Connection Timeout**

Comment: either you had a change on the server, which could be everything. or your change is something building up and crashing now when a limit is reached (e.g. filesystem full). If you have an 301 you propably run into a timeout when connecting to ??? (something unknown) where the connection previously worked (and was fast). so maybe another server involved changed, not your TYPO3 installation.

Comment: i can definitely exclude that error is caused by typo3 installation. I did an typo3 upgrade and error still occurs. Furthermore I updated all server modules, did also not help.

What is strange: All pages are always loaded after exactly 1.8 minutes. Maybe there's an recursive loop that get's broken after 1.8 mins?

Comment: 100sec timeout? try to identify the nettraffic in your browser (firebug, ...), a 301 redirect also seems to be wrong. then have a look into your server log. any 301 should be logged there also. you might enable rewrite-log of the server to see further relocations.

Comment: Is RAM bigger than before?  Were any tunables changed?

Comment: A complete reboot of the server fixed the bug temporary although the error still occurs sporadic. Our server administrator will keep on fixing this bug. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

**Can you activate the scheduler extension and execute garbage collection tasks?**
Then see, if that helps

**Do you have access to the server and can you restart services?**
Then try restarting apache

I had a similar situation once, the issue was based on wrong permissions and php session files that could not be deleted. Switching to memcache session handling for php solved the issue.